# Bibliography style with bold name list (format entire list at once)

Tags: bibliographies

Could you please suggest me which style should I use to get the bibliography in the style reported in the picture below?

The entire author/editor name lists is bold (including the "and", so it makes sense to format it as one unit), followed by the year of publication in parentheses.

Author/editor names should be given in the format *last name, first initials, junior part*, e.g.

> Costa, P.T., Jr. and McCrae, R.R.

[image]

Comment: You can try `biblatex-apa`  which is close to this.

Comment: @Bernard. Thanks for your prompt reply. So I can get also authors' name in bold and title in Italics with biblatex-apa?

Comment: Normally, titles in italics for book, titles upright and journal title in italics for articles (this is the general layout). You may have to patch some details to obtain exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `biblatex` it should be possible to cook something up. Some aspects of the style may be more complicated to implement than others.

Although the desired style seems to share some elements with APA style (the name format) this answer does not build upon `biblatex-apa`. It can be quite complicated to apply even simple modifications to `biblatex-apa`, since the style has to do a lot to implement the complex requirements of the APA manual.

Instead I based the answer on `ext-authoryear` of my [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) style bundle, since the bundle offers a few shortcuts for some of the required modifications.

`biblatex` 3.12 introduced new name and list wrappers that allow you to easily typeset an entire name list in bold and not just parts of it (as is currently possible). This is what the

```
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

does, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/754 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/829.

Other than that the most complicated redefinitions involves the name format, the rest is fairly straightforward (cf. [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864)).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Junicode}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, dashed=false,
  articlein=false,
  alldates=year, urldate=long]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{}

\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{\mkcomprange{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\locdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{costamccrae1988,
  author  = {Costa, Jr., Paul. T. and Robert R. McCrae},
  title   = {Personality in Adulthood:
             A Six-Year Longitudinal Study of Self-Reports
             and Spouse Ratings on the {NEO} Personality Inventory},
  journal = {Journal of Personality and Social Psychology},
  date    = {1988-05},
  volume  = {54},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {853-863},
}
@book{costamccrae1992,
  author    = {Costa, Jr., Paul. T. and Robert R. McCrae},
  title     = {Revised {NEO} Personality Inventory ({NEO-PI-R})
               and {NEO} Five-Factor Inventory ({NEO-FFI})
               Professional Manual},
  date      = {1992},
  location  = {Odessa, Florida},
  publisher = {Psychological Assessment Resources},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,costamccrae1988,costamccrae1992}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Costa, P.T., Jr. and McCrae, R.R. (1988) Personality in Adulthood: A Six-Year Longitudinal Study of Self-Reports and Spouse Ratings on the NEO Personality Inventory, Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, 54.5, 853–63.//Costa,P.T.,Jr.andMcCrae,R.R.(1992) Revised NEO Personality Inventory (NEO-PI-R) and NEO Five-Factor Inventory (NEO-FFI) Professional Manual, Psychological Assessment Resources, Odessa, Florida.//Sigfridsson, E. and Ryde, U. (1998) Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments, Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19.4, 377–95, DOI: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: I tried to run your code and I got the following error message: 

example.tex
17
Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \DeclareNameWrapperFormat
                              {sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
Any suggestion?

Comment: @Dario ` \DeclareNameWrapperFormat` is going to be a feature of the *upcoming* version 3.12. It has not yet been released (I expect it to come out in hopefully a week or so), so you will have to wait for a bit before you can use that particular line. I should probably have made that clearer in the answer, sorry. For the time being comment it out.

Comment: Oh my fault. Thanks a lot for your reply. I will save the code waiting for the update :)

Comment: @Dario `biblatex` 3.12 has been released and is available in TeX live (2018) and MikTeX as of this morning (UTC). That means that the complete code above should work with the current version of `biblatex` as intended.

Comment: @moewe would you care to edit the title of the question to make it at all sensical to future readers? I mean, I know the Q was asking about implementing a picture, but you're explaining a new feature in your answer, which isn't nothing, and I'm confident you can picture what someone, who should be directed to this answer, would be looking for. Anyways, you know better how SEOs and tex.se works than me, so I'll leave it to you.

Comment: @thymaro I gave it a shot, feel free to improve my edit. It can be really hard to find a good title for questions like this, especially when the just ask to *implement that style*.

Comment: @moewe looks fine to me. I commend the additions to the text, too!