# How can I change bibliograpy spacing?

Tags: biblatex, spacing, bibliographies

Here's my WME

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5 cm, bottom=2.5 cm, left=4 cm, right=2.5 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=numeric, bibstyle=authoryear, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{dnm.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{[\printfield{labelnumber}]\addspace}
\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand\bibname{Kaynakça}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
Latex is the best \cite{alman}.
But sometimes it's hard \cite{pdf_26}.
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=KAYNAKLAR]

\end{document}
```

and my result

[image: what i got]

but I need this kind of setting

[image: what i want]

For that I need

1. a space between items
2. that interesting indent thing,
   Thank you very much...

Comment: I suggest you split off the question about bold names (point 3) into a new question. Its answer will have nothing to do with the other two points. `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat` would be my weapon of choice here.

Comment: Point 1 can probably be solved with something like `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}`.

Comment: \DeclareNameWrapperFormat  gave me intent but took the [1] numbers from me.
Point 1 is solved immediately. Thank you.

Comment: Huh? It should not indent anything. It should make the names bold if instructed to do so.

Comment: Yea I put it the right place with the right way and all the names are bold now.

Comment: As I say, please ask a new question about that if you have issues with the solution. (And even if you don't have issues it would be nice to have a Q&A that shows how it works.) See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456812/35864

Answer (score 1):

The space between items can be controlled with `\bibitemsep`.

The "hanging indent" can be introduced by redefining the bibliography environment to modify `\itemindent` based on `\bibhang`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibhang}{4em}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibhang}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-\itemindent}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum,cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with additional indent for non-first lines in each entry]